# Record a Hangout Session without being present

Tags: google-hangouts

We want to create hangout sessions with a master (altough this assistant will not be present in the session). So, is it possible to record all those sessions and store them somehow by programming? For example, in the master Google Drive account? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question it's very vague and seems more like you are looking for a recording software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is not possible to achieve by programming what you cannot do through the UI

Through the UI it is not possible to record an meeting in which one does not participate which is good for safety reasons.

Just imagine you are having a meeting with someone and think it is a private meeting - but actually somebody is recording it in the background without your knowledge.